# Проблемы при работе с БД при подключении JS

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

Здравствуйте!

Пишу авторизацию пользователей. И возникла такая проблема. Сначала делала без AJAX-запросов, просто если пользователь находился в БД, делала

echo 'Привет, ' . $user;

Все получалось. Основной код вот

```
$Login    = $_POST['login'];
$Password = $_POST['password'];

$sql      = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '$Login'";
$res      = mysql_query($sql, $db);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($res); // ищем пользователя в БД, подсчитываем кол-во строк в выборке

$secret = 'dvornPenza';
if ($num_rows == 0) {
    echo 'Пользователя с таким логином не существует';
}

else {
    $Result   = mysql_fetch_array($res);
    $user     = $Result[name];
    $PWD      = $Result[pdw_md5]; // берем пароль из БД
    $Password = $Password . 'dvornPenza';
    $PWD2     = md5($Password); // шифруем введенный пароль

    if ($PWD == $PWD2) //проверяем совпадает ли введенный кэш с требуемым
        {
        $_SESSION[id]   = $Result[id]; //заносим данные в сессию
        $_SESSION[name] = $user;
        echo 'Привет, ' . $user;
    } else {
        echo 'Неверный пароль';
    }
}
```

Но только как решила подключить

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="registr.js"></script>
```

переменная $num_rows  становится нулевой. То ли подключение к БД пропадает, то ли не знаю. Подскажите, кто знает, что здесь не так.

**Добавлено из комментария.**

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="registr.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Это подключение скриптов, а сам registr.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'reg.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: $('form').serialize()
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('h2').text(data);
        });
    });

});
```

Без перезагрузки страницы нужно поменять заголовок формы "Вход для своих" на "Привет, user".

**Добавлено из комментария.**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title> Дворники </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styledvornik.css"> 
</head>
<body>
<form action="auto.php" method="post">
<h2> Вход для своих</h2>
<div class="field">
<input id="lf-login" type="text" name="login" />
</div>
<div class="field">
<input id="lf-password" type="password" name="password" />
</div>

<div class="field">
<button class="j-submit-login-form"> </button>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</form>  
<script src="jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="registr.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Анна, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: Ну больше данных нужно, как отправляются данные откуда и куда что в JS файлах написано?

еще август и не все экстрасенсы вернулись из отпусков.

Comment: Т.е. в РАБОЧИЙ код вы подключаете 2 скрипта (в хтмл, с правильными путями). Страница продолжает загружаться, но пропадает подключение? Этого не может быть, потому что этого не может быть никогда :)

Comment: Ну почему-то это происходит...

Comment: а подключаю в index.php..

Comment: покажите как подключаете... кусок кода с подключенными скриптами

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

в куске кода добавить

```
var_dump($_POST);// это

$Login    = $_POST['login'];
$Password = $_POST['password'];

$sql      = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '".$Login."'"; // подправить '".$Login."'
echo $sql; // это тоже проверить, просто вывести.
$res      = mysql_query($sql, $db);
```

Собственно после добавления 2х строк можно кинуть обновление в вопрос, тогда понятнее будет. Т.к. соединение с БД пропасть просто так не может, а значит ошибка не в этом.

**//UPD** попробуй так

```
$Login    = iconv("WINDOWS-1251","UTF-8",$_POST['login']);
```

Старайся чтобы во всех, без исключения, файлах была одна и та же кодировка!

и добавь тут кодировку, и вполне возможно, что верхний костыль можно будет убрать.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title> Дворники </title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> // это!
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styledvornik.css"> 
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: array(2) {
  ["login"]=>
  string(8) "РРІР°РЅ"
  ["password"]=>
  string(3) "111"
}
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = 'РРІР°РЅ'0Пользователя с таким логином не существует

это смотрю во вкладке Network-> Preview

значит из-за кодировки..потому что в поле логина я написала "Иван",а в БД он хранится как "Èâàí"..только почему без js эта разница в кодировке не появляется..

Comment: Ну значит нужно сохранить js в правильной кодировке (предположительно в utf8). Ведь аякс запрос идет именно с этих файлов, и если они в неправильной кодировке, то и запрос отправляется в этой кодировке...

Comment: А как js сохранять в нужной кодировке? Прямо в файле registr.js что-то указать?

Comment: попыталась вот так
<script src="registr.js" charset="utf-8"></script> 

но ничего не изменилось..

Answer (score 0):

Блин, при чём тут кодировка js-файлов?
AJAX-запрос по определению отправляется в UTF-8.
Если в БД данные в другой кодировке, значит надо то, что приходит в массив $_POST, преобразовывать к кодировке БД. Например так:

```
$login = iconv('UTF-8', '_кодировка_БД_', $_POST['login']);
```

P.S. Должно быть установлено расширение iconv для PHP

P.P.S.  Кстати, а где <meta charset="*хоть_что_нибудь*" /> в вашем index.php?

P.P.P.S. А где атрибут type у тега script?